# How to declare a new property for an object in an npm package?

Tags: typescript

Code:

```
import * as request from 'superagent';

request
    .get('https://***.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/')
    .proxy(this.options.proxy)
```

TypeScript Error

```
Property 'proxy' does not exist on type 'SuperAgentRequest'
```

Type annotatations for request

```
(alias) namespace request
(alias) const request: request.SuperAgentStatic
import request
```

My attempt at type definitions (that is not successful in getting rid of the TypeScript error):

```
declare module superagent {
    interface SuperAgentRequest {
        proxy: any;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong in the declaration file?

Answer (score 0):

First, don't forget to put doubles quotes around superagent, when you declare the module.

Assumed, you have no types to augment and declare the package from scratch, put following in its own `.d.ts` file like globals.d.ts:

```
declare module "superagent" {
  interface SuperAgentRequest {
    proxy: any;
  }

  export function get(s: string): SuperAgentRequest;
}
```

From a file module, you could then write:

```
import * as request from "superagent";

request
  // get returns request.SuperAgentRequest
  .get("https://***.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/")
  .proxy(this.options.proxy);
```